# Jars for Seam API: FileNotFoundException during deployment

Tags: jsf, seam, jboss6.x

i've got a problem deploying my WAR bundling seam, seam-ui and seam-debug. When I start the JBossAS 6 Final from eclipse 3.8 or from run.bat under Win7 x64, I get the following Exception:

```
12:17:06,383 WARN  [URLScanner] could not read entries: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\deploy\aboutme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-seam-2.2.2.Final.jar ([The system could not find the path])
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.handleArchiveByFile(URLScanner.java:123) [:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.handle(URLScanner.java:107) [:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.scanResources(URLScanner.java:90) [:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.StandardDeploymentStrategy.scan(StandardDeploymentStrategy.java:119) [:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.create(Initialization.java:130) [:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36) [:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:477) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
[...]
```

for all three seam jars. What might be the reason for JBossAS not to be able to read the mentioned directory?

In eclipse, I checked "Deploy as compressed archive." (The same error occured without that check mark).

Any advice is appreciated.
Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

Well, kind of yes. The point is, that it has to work with only the archive deployed. so there is no exploded folder, which follows this structure. but ih I follow the path to the archive and go on exploring it further to WEB-INF\lib, then, yes, I found the jars.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the path `C:\jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\deploy\aboutme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-seam-2.2.2.Final.jar` actually contains this file?